# DropDownList allow user to select "Name" but create "ID" in the DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, crud

I am trying to create a web application which will allow users to select a training course from DB, then 'apply' to this course. There application will be logged in "CourseRequests" table.

I have a table called "InternalCourses"
I have a tabled called "CourseRequests"

I have build a CREATE.CSHTML page which allows the user to select a course, and then hit 'create' it should create a record in the relevant table. My problem is because I need the user to select a CourseName, and have the program send back the relevant ID to the database, and discard the coursename.
A screenshot of this page looks like so: [image: LINK]

My Controller class:

```
    // GET: CourseRequests/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.InternalCourses = db.InternalCourses.ToList();
        ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "FirstName");
        ViewBag.ManagerID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "ManagerID", "FirstName");
        ViewBag.CourseID = new SelectList(db.ExternalCourses, "CourseID", "CourseName");
        ViewBag.CourseID = new SelectList(db.InternalCourses, "CourseID", "CourseName");
        ViewBag.CourseID = new SelectList(db.TrainingFeedbacks, "CourseID", "Question");
        return View();
    }
```

My Create.cshtml

```
<!-- CourseID-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseID, "CourseID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseID, new SelectList(ViewBag.InternalCourses, "CourseID", "CourseName"), new { @class = "form-control" } )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

My (relevant) model diagram:
[image: DB Model]
The image shows a link from `InternalCourse.CourseID`, to `CourseRequest.CourseID` please note that the table CourseRequests, does not contain "CourseName" only ID.

Please could somebody advise me where I'm going wrong, I can see that I'm trying to put CourseName into ID field but don't get how I can change this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters you define `ViewBag.CourseID` three times, which is a total waste of resources as only the last time will stick. The first two are just wasted queries:

```
ViewBag.CourseID = new SelectList(db.ExternalCourses, "CourseID", "CourseName");
ViewBag.CourseID = new SelectList(db.InternalCourses, "CourseID", "CourseName");
ViewBag.CourseID = new SelectList(db.TrainingFeedbacks, "CourseID", "Question");
```

Next, when using `ViewBag` to store your select lists, you need to be careful not to clobber any of your model data. Anything in `ModelState` (which `ViewBag` is a part of) overrides anything on your model. Therefore, you'll never be able to show the selected value for the property `CourseID` when you have a select list stored in `ViewBag.CourseID` because the value will always be the select list itself, not what item was selected. Use a different name such as `ViewBag.CourseChoices`.

Finally, I'm not sure what problem you're actually having here. There is no difficulty in showing one thing as choices in a select list, like a name, while submitting something else, like an id. The constructor for `SelectList` should be called in the following format:

```
new SelectList(listOfItems, propertyToUseAsValue, propertyToUseAsText)
```

So, in your scenario, as long as you feed it "CourseID" and "CourseName", in that order, you'll get what you want. It's possible some of these other issues I mentioned are actually the source of your issues.